# How to pass complex type parameters from Flash-AS3 to a web service?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

i've the following snip of code in AS3:

```
var myWebService = new WebService();
myWebService.addEventListener("load", loadDone);
myWebService.loadWSDL("wsdl_address");
var myOperation:Operation;
function loadDone(evt:LoadEvent)
{
    myOperation = Operation(myWebService.getOperation("method_name"));
    myOperation.addEventListener("fault", wsError);
    myOperation.addEventListener("result", wsResult);
    //myOperation.send();

    var input:Object = new Object();
?????
?????   
    myOperation.arguments = input;
    myOperation.send();
}
```

my WS has a complex type named

```
tkt
    code1:string
    code2:string
    code3:string
```

How can i pass values to tkt complex type in webservice?

Thanks in advance !
c.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this? If you figured it out, post and answer please!

Answer (score 0):

MyOperation.request = input, or something like that, IIRC. Operation.request is what you are looking for I believe.